# SQL Server Express 2012. Creating an audit using profiler

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-profiler, audit-logging

SQL Server 2012. Using SQL Server Profiler. How can I set the trace to only display to the results table audit type details? Such as whoever logged in, when a user makes a CRUD query, date and time etc. Just to be able to log and see who made changes in case anything happens at the database level.
Basically I do not want to include all of the stored procedures from displaying. 
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on new trace in the profiler, go to Events Selection tab in the trace properties window and select whichever event you want to log.

Regards,
Sumit